# Return struct type confirming to protocols

Tags: swift, struct, protocols

Here is my piece of code,

```
protocol Configuration {

    static var url: String { get }
    static var username: String { get }
    static var password: String { get }
}

protocol Server {

    associatedtype Profile: Configuration
    associatedtype Payment: Configuration
    associatedtype Images: Configuration
}

struct Development: Server {

    struct Profile: Configuration {

        static var url: String { return "http://google.com" }
        static var username: String { return "abc" }
        static var password: String { return "xyz" }
    }

    struct Payment: Configuration {

        static var url: String { return "http://bing.com" }
        static var username: String { return "abc" }
        static var password: String { return "xyz" }
    }

    struct Images: Configuration {

        static var url: String { return "http://duckduckgo.com" }
        static var username: String { return "abc" }
        static var password: String { return "xyz" }
    }
}

struct Production: Server {

    struct Profile: Configuration {

        static var url: String { return "http://amazon.com" }
        static var username: String { return "pqr" }
        static var password: String { return "xyz" }
    }

    struct Payment: Configuration {

        static var url: String { return "http://facebook.com" }
        static var username: String { return "pqr" }
        static var password: String { return "xyz" }
    }

    struct Images: Configuration {

        static var url: String { return "http://orkut.com" }
        static var username: String { return "pqr" }
        static var password: String { return "xyz" }
    }
}
```

Question is I would like to fetch my 'struct' (depending on my environment). I need something like,

```
struct Environment {

    static func current() -> Any:Server {

        if #DEBUG
            return Development
        #endif

        return Production
    }
}
```

But returning a specific type confirming to my protocol is not possible.

Any suggestion on this or a different approach will be helpful.

Comment: Do you want current() to return the struct type? Not an instance of the struct?

Comment: @andlin Yes, then only I would be able to use static properties inside it,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Development" and "Production" are values, not types. You don't need protocols here and shouldn't be using them. Just create the values you need and return them:

```
struct Server {
    let url: String
    let username: String
    let password: String
}

struct Environment {
    let profile: Server
    let payment: Server
    let images: Server

    static let development = Environment(
        profile: Server(url: "http://google.com", username: "abc", password: "xyz"),
        payment: Server(url: "http://bing.com", username: "abc", password: "xyz"),
        images: Server(url: "http://duckduckgo.com", username: "abc", password: "xyz")
    )

    static let production = Environment(...)

    static var current: Environment {
        #if DEBUG
            return development
        #else
            return production
        #endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited to simplify it a bit more. There was no reason for three levels of struct; just two.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a generic type or you can simply do something like this:

```
struct Config {

  static var BaseURL: URL {
    switch Environment.current {
      case .debug:
        return URL(string: "https://...dev.com")!
      case .staging:
        return URL(string: "https://...staging.com")!
      case .release:
        return URL(string: "https://...production.com")!
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return `Server`, not `Any:Server`:

```
static func current() -> Server {

    if #DEBUG
        return Development
    #endif

    return Production
}
```

Comment: Server is a Protocol. Error: Protocol 'Server' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Comment: Agreed that this won't fix it, but Andreas is correct that `Any: Server` (for any protocol, not just `Server`) would always be wrong. You can't avoid the "generic constraint" problem just by throwing "Any" in there.